# Loading a html snippet from another html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have an external .html file, from which I will load snippets programatically, and insert them in the document at runtime. I did it like this in my `index.html`

```
<head>
   <link rel="import" href="html/html_snippets.html">
</head>
```

This is the example content of the `html_snippets.html` file

```
<div id="asd">
   <some stuff here>
</div>
```

Then after everything is loaded, I load the snippet like this

```
var friendSnippet = $("#asd").html();
```

The problem I am facing now is that I use the jQuery code in a loop, which runs several times, and the first time it always returns an undefined, but after that it's fine.

Why is that happening?

Comment: do you use jQuery(window).load(function () { for checking if page is fully loaded before html load script. also it should not loop if its not inside a loop :)

Comment: I do everything after $(document).ready(function () {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery .load() function to load an html file into a certain element on the page.

```
$("#destinationElement").load("path/to/file.html");
```

This may solve the issue.

Comment: but I am planning to use many snippets from that html file, will it be a good idea to load the document every time with jQuery load?

Comment: You should test it, I don't know how it will handle loading